# MSTeams : How can I get the live participant data while the Teams meeting is going on (Live)?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Here, I'm building up the teams application where the application is able to run on the teams meeting itself. but the behaviour of application is such a that I need to find a or mount the attendee numbers in list including the Host. That is why I need a live meeting participant data whether from teams SDK/GRAPHAPI or from anywhere else.

I tried with the live-share SDK's but unable to get it. also tried out the GRAPH_API but graph api provides the static data not dynamic (live)

Comment: We also tested the graph API for fetching attendeereport for an live meeting but we are also getting the static data not dynamic.
We are checking this with the engineering team we will update you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe for change notification for online meetings.
You can get the below event notification:

- CallStarted - Occurs when the meeting call has started.
- CallEnded - Occurs when the meeting call has ended.
- CallRosterUpdate - Occurs when a participant joins or exits the
  meeting call.

In CallRosterUpdate you will get the active participants joined and exited list.

Example of Response

```
{
  "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Graph.onlineMeeting",
  "@odata.id":"communications/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl+eq+'{joinWebUrl}'",
  "id":"communications/onlineMeetings?$filter=joinWebUrl+eq+'{joinWebUrl}'",
  "eventType":"Microsoft.Communication.CallRosterUpdate",
  "eventDateTime":"2022-02-28T00:00:00.0000000Z",
  "activeParticipants@joined": [
    {
      "Id": "a4d67b60-56a5-4202-9f1c-f123ff40621e",
      "Identity": 
      {
        "User": 
        {
          "Id": "f92ca67f-0564-414b-8caa-8c95b8099928",
          "DisplayName": "user display name",
          "TenantId": "85045508-f5bd-405e-a553-52700f86e29c"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "activeParticipants@exited": [
    {
      "Id": "11141402-1b62-4795-b540-4ffee8544231",
      "Identity": 
      {
        "AzureCommunicationServicesUser": 
        {
          "AzureCommunicationServicesResourceId": "534c244d-49f8-47a1-9e8e-70d115a2ef4d",
          "Id": "8:acs:534c244d-49f8-47a1-9e8e-70d115a2ef4d_28f01a7b-42cd-4e37-ae1a-bd653377f4b7",
          "DisplayName": "acs user display name"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note that currently its supported only in beta version.
Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/changenotifications-for-onlinemeeting

Comment: How can I call the Beta API out 
I'm using the below URL it actually gives me error in graph API
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/communications/onlineMeetings?$filter=JoinWebUrl eq '{joinWebUrl}'

Comment: This is the error that I'm getting : 
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Unexpected segment DynamicPathSegment. Expected property/$value.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-11-09T04:05:14",
            "request-id": "...",
            "client-request-id": "..."
        }
    }
}

Comment: Could you please share which API you are testing? You can use graph explorer or Postman to test the API.